# how to get input field value onclick into ifram with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have  field and  and one . I just need to use jQuery to add the src OR href of iframe which get value from input field on click function.

```
<input type="text">
<button></button>

<ifram src=""></ifram>
```

I need perfect Solution if anyone help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reference the elements, and set the attribute when the user clicks the button.

```js
$('#button').click(() => {
  $('#iframe').attr('src', $('#input').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="button">Set iframe</button>

<iframe src="example.com" id="iframe"></iframe>
```